How can I alter the element markup in a multi-step form?
I have built a multistep webform using webform version 6.2.2 and Drupal 10 and I want to show a summary element on each step that updates with the information of user input from all previous pages.
The summary element is a processed text/HTML element that can be either a single field outside the step wrapper or separate fields inside each step.
What I have tried so far is altering the element in the form validate callback like this:
function THEME_multistep_validate(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface 
 &$form_state){
 if ($form['progress']['#current_page'] == "step_2") {
  $form['elements']['step_2']['summary']['#text'] = '<h2>STEP 1 complete</h2>';
 }
}

As well as in the wizard_next form action:
function THEME_multistep_step_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface  &$form_state)
{
   $form['elements']['step_2']['summary']['#text'] = '<h2>STEP 1 complete</h2>';

}

added in the form_alter hook like this:
  array_unshift($form['actions']['wizard_next']['#submit'], 'THEME_multistep_step_submit');

In both ways, the form handlers are called and the $form array reflects the changes but the element is still rendered with the initial value and not updated, regardless if the element is outside or inside the steps/pages of the form. Am I missing something here or is there a better approach for this? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Edit: I found this question about a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54582371/drupal-8-webform-how-to-display-text-input-on-one-page-on-the-next-page but the solution is for changing values of actual input fields, wheareas I am trying to change content of a text/HTML element added via the webform UI.

Did you try hook_form_alter the hooks you used just for validation and submit, if you want to alter elements of the form you need hook form alter

Yes I added the custom handler functions inside the form_alter hook in both cases and they are executed and alter the $form object but the element is not rendered with the updated values.

I finally solved it like this, all inside the form_alter hook:
function [MODULE_NAME]_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id === "YOU_FORM_ID") {

    /* setup summary string */
    $summary_string = "You selected: ";

    /* check if a user input value for field a is present /*
    $field_a = $form_state->getValue("field_a");

    if (!empty($field_a)) {
      /* append to summary string */
      $summary_string = $summary_string.$field_a;
    }

    /* check if a user input value for field b is present /*
    $field_b = $form_state->getValue("field_b");

    if (!empty($field_b)) {
      /* append to summary string */
      $summary_string = $summary_string." and ".$field_b;
    }

    /* update text of summary element with the string */
    $form['elements']['summary']['#text'] = $summary_string;

  }
}

So there is actually no need for handling this in the validation or the wizard_next action.

The alter of the processed text/HTML element is a little bit tricky because it doesn't go through the same process as the other elements.
You can see more information here: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/6.2.x/src/Plugin/WebformElement/ProcessedText.php
So to alter processed text/HTML element you need to make changes in the webform entity elements, like this:
I'm not sure if this is the best way to do so but it works and i didn't find another way.


/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function [MODULE_NAME]_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === "YOU_FORM_ID") {
    /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission */
    $webform_submission = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    /** @var \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform $webform */
    $webform = $webform_submission->getWebform();
    $webform_elements = $webform->getElementsDecoded();
    // Change your processed text here.
    // You can get the submitted values from the previous step.
    // This is the case were the element is part of the step.
    $webform_elements['step_2']['summary']['#text'] = 'Hello this changed text';
    $form['progress']['#webform']->setElements($webform_elements);
  }
}



Altering the element inside the _form_alter hook works fine if I just set the #text value like this: $form['elements']['summary']['#text'].
But I want it to update after each previous/next page change from inside the custom form handler added via $form['actions']['wizard_next']['#submit'][] = '[MODULE_NAME]_custom_multi_page_submit'.
Strangely, this works once using your approach, but defaults back to the elements initial value in each of the consecutive page changes. I tried adding $form_state->setRebuild(true); but that didn't change anything.
